# differentiate records based on table name in join query

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am using `join` query in `MySQL` to fetch records from multiple tables.
What i want to do is to just differentiate records based on table name.

For example,

```
1)Table1

name
test1
test2

2)Table2

name
test3
test4
```

After `join` it will give me all records like this,

```
name
test1
test2
test3
test4
```

I just want output like this

```
name    from_table
test1   table1
test2   table1
test3   table2
test4   table2
```

What is the best way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need a join, you can use a UNION ALL query and a constant column:

```
SELECT name, 'table1' AS fromtable
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT name, 'table2' AS fromtable
FROM table2
```